# SQL Oracle coding with primary(foreign) key and references

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi guys I am new to SQL and I'm trying to create 2 tables: employee and department with one column from a table that refer 2 columns from the other table, to link them to each other.

```
create table Employee
(
        employee_id Number,
        firstname varchar2(50 char),
        lastname varchar2(50 char),
        gender varchar2 (2 char),
        position varchar2(50 char),
        department_id number Not null,
        salary number Not null,
        Constraint employee_pk Primary key(employee_id)
);

create table products
(
        department_id Number, not null,
        department_name varchar2(50 char),
        Constraint products_fk Foreign key (department_id)
        references employee(department_id)
        );
```

Error report -

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong with that, I think the problem are the keys, I want to refer the department(department_id and department_name) to the department_id from the employee table....can anyone explain me what is the problem?  [Image of the 2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFjG.png)

Answer (score 3):

Error you got says that there's an invalid column name, and yes - there is, because of a superfluous comma, in the `CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS` here:

```
department_id Number, not null,
                    ^
                    this
```

Once you fix it and run the command again, you get this error:

```
  5          Constraint products_fk Foreign key (department_id)
  6          references employee(department_id)
  7          );
        references employee(department_id)
                            *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

It means that you can't create a foreign key which points to a column that is not unique nor primary key in the `employee` table. In there, the primary key is `employee_id`, which is correct. It wouldn't make sense to make the `department_id` column a primary key as, obviously, more than a single employee can work in the same department so you'd violate uniqueness.

If you think twice, does it even make sense to reference a department within the `employee` table? I'd say not, but it would make a perfect sense to reference the `department_id` that is the primary key in the `department` table.

But hey! Your `product` table looks exactly like the `department` should - it has `department_id, department_name` columns. What kind of a "product" is that? Are you sure you made it right?

The following code makes much more sense to me; wouldn't you agree?

```
SQL> -- former PRODUCT table
SQL> CREATE TABLE department (
  2    department_id     NUMBER
  3      CONSTRAINT pk_depart PRIMARY KEY,
  4    department_name   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE employee (
  2    employee_id     NUMBER,
  3    firstname       VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  4    lastname        VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  5    gender          VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),
  6    position        VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  7    department_id   NUMBER NOT NULL
  8      CONSTRAINT fk_emp_dept
  9        REFERENCES department ( department_id ),
 10    salary          NUMBER NOT NULL,
 11    CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY ( employee_id )
 12  );

Table created.

SQL>
```